# JQuery anchor click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying a way to click a anchor tag using Jquery which is inside multiple div.

Below is my code:

```
<div class="mainDiv">
    <div id="secondDiv" class="check">
        <div class="iteratorDiv1" id="id1">
            <a href="url">link text</a>
        </div>
        <div class="iteratorDiv2" id="id2">
            <a href="url">link text</a>
        </div>
        <div class="iteratorDiv3" id="id3">
            <a href="url">link text</a>
        </div>
        <div class="iteratorDiv4" id="id4">
            <a href="url">link text</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now if i do something like this

```
$(".iteratorDiv1 a").live('click',function(e)
{
    alert("hey working");
});
```

But using this approach i will have to write this function for `iteratorDiv2`,`iteratorDiv3` and `iteratorDiv4` also.
Is there any way i can identify the anchor click from the `mainDiv` something like below. This did not work though.

```
$(".mainDiv a").live('click',function(e)
{
     alert("hey working");
});
```

I am just trying to prevent repeatative coding. Any guidance.

Comment: `$(".iteratorDiv1 a, .mainDiv a")....`. Use `.on('click', ` for jQuery 1.7+

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the `.live()` method is deprecated. Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: 1) Yes - use the `this` keyword to get a reference to the element which raised the event 2) `live()` was deprecated a *long* time ago. You should use `on()` instead, and make sure you're using an up to date version of jQuery - 1.12 at the oldest

Comment: there are many ways this could be done. You could add a handler class to all the div's and this way you could call them in one go.. or you could give a common class name to your anchor tags and that could be a easy identifier too.

Comment: I cant give common class name to all anchor tags as they all have some purpose.

Comment: @Satpal i am using JQuery 1.10

Comment: You can use `$(".mainDiv a").on('click',function(e)
    {
        alert("hey working");
    }); ` To identify parent you can use `$(this).parent().is('.iteratorDiv1')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the following jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/amoolya93/1xL9od85/3/

Your code works fine until Jquery version 1.8.3 .For later versions, please use the following:

```
         $('.mainDiv a').on('click',function(e)
             {    alert("hey working");
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

I just did some test here, and seem to work.
You might tell jQuery where exactly your "a" is, so you can try something like this:

```
$(".mainDiv div > a").on("click", function () {
    alert("Hey it's working");
});
```

or

```
$(".mainDiv a").on("click", function () {
    alert("Hey it's working");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$("a").on('click',function(e)
{
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    alert(parent.attr(class)) ;
});
```

Use [.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) method to get parent of any link you clicked.